# Adding a parameter to a url in netsuite via online form

Tags: parameters, netsuite, online-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic web link for a customer survey that automatically fills the customer record field so that the imported data from the customer is accurate. However, i am using an online form and not through a script. Do i need to create a script that then adds the parameter?

If so how do i create the script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you generating the link in the first place?

Comment: I've created a new form called Customer Survey, and with it i can generate an "online form" and within the online form there is an "external link" tab.

Answer (score 0):

How public is the link to the form? Does it create an easy to script customer data mine? When doing anything that pulls customer data into a form

What I have done for mail out links is to put two custom fields on customer records. These are a hash and an expiration time stamp.

Before a campaign mailing I populate the fields. The expiration depends on the timeframe to respond.

These fields and the customerid are used to create query parameters on the inbound link to the form. The hash uses the customerid, time stamp and a secret.

The form gets a client script that reads those parameters and sends them off to a suitelet.

If the hash and time stamp validate then the suitelet responds with the customer details for the form.

Comment: This is basically a link sent to customers through netsuite. i wasnt to add parameters and the suiteanswers article: 9417 says to 
-add a create a parameter that will be added to the end of the publishable form url.
-i can't seem to find the place where you can add a paremter. the only thing i see is an option to add a script to the online form
-I can't edit the publishable url to add the fields to the end of the url

Comment: You just copy the publishable URL and add whatever parameters you need to the end.  The script you can add to the form will look for that parameter (hashed as described above) and send the id, hash and time stamp to a suitelet which will provide the customer info.